# Poisson Formula yielding number too large and can't seem to figure out why.

Tags: probability, statistics

So the formula is $ P(X) = \frac{e^-U \cdot U^X }{X!}$.

My average rate of success is $\frac 1 2 $. The number I'm testing is 4. The question wants me to work out the chance of there being more than 4 successes in a day, so I must get the probability of 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. All of them appeared to be okay, but when I got to 4, I'm getting an answer of $ 1.579... \cdot 10^{-3}$ and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $ e^{-U} $?

Comment: Do your values add up to very close to $1$?  Why do you think that value for $4$ is wrong-it is eight times the expectation.

Comment: @kummerer94: user205131 must have used $e^{-U}$ to get  $1.579\times 10^{−3}$

Comment: Yeah, formula was a typo. Anyone know how I can work this into a percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine.  If you add the probabilities of $0$ to $4$ you get very close to $1$, so the chance of more than $4$ events is very small.  In fact, $P(5)=1.579\cdot 10^{-4}$ and higher numbers are much smaller, so that is essentially the chance of more than $4$.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Oh. I didn't realise 1.579.19^-4 was less than one. How would I convert that into a percentile figure? Or would it essentially be 0.0%?

Comment: It is not less than zero.  It is positive, though rather small.  As a decimal it is $0.0001579$ and as usual if you want to express it as percent you multiply by $100$, getting $0.01579\%$

Comment: Oh God embarrassing. Don't know why I was thinking zero. And thanks so much for your answer, this clears everything up! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$, then
$$ \mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$
for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. In this case, $\lambda = \frac12$, so
$$\mathbb P(X>4) = 1 - \mathbb P(X\leqslant 4)=1-\sum_{k=0}^4\mathbb P(X=k)=1-\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{e^{-\frac12}\left(\frac12\right)^k}{k!}.$$
Computing this quantity we get
$$ 1 - \frac{211}{128}e^{-\frac12}\approx 1.7216\cdot 10^{-4}.$$
In particular, $\mathbb P(X=4) = e^{-\frac12}\left(\frac12\right)^4\frac1{4!}\approx1.5795\cdot 10^{-3}$, so you were computing it correctly.